# FTP: 421 Data timeout on Azure VM

Tags: python, azure, ftp, ftplib

I have a simple script that successfully downloads a 75MB file over FTP:

```
    try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
    ftp.login(username,  password)
    ftp.cwd(source_dir)
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    print('Ftp error = ', e)
    return False

# Check filename exists
if filename in ftp.nlst():
        local_filename = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, lf.write)
        lf.close()
        print(filename, ' successfully downloaded')
else:
        print(filename, ' not found in the path ',  source_dir)
ftp.quit()
```

This script works fine on both my home and work laptops when run from Spyder IDE or a Windows scheduled task.

I have deployed the exact same script to a Windows Virtual Machine on Azure.

- Files less than 10MB seem to download ok.
- Files larger than 30MB return an exception:
  ***421 Data timeout. Reconnect. Sorry.***
- I get around 700 Mbps on Azure and only around 8Mbps on my home network.
- It looks like a timeout.  I can see the file is partially downloaded.

I tried setting ftp.set_pasv(False), but this then returns me 500 Illegal Port, which is to be expected.  I understand passive is the preferred approach anyhow.

What else can I do to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: How long does it take before you get the exception? How much data gets downloaded?

Comment: Differs, usually around 15-20MB downloads.  Will get some times later.

Answer (score 1):

Just some suggestions for you.

1. According to the wiki page for [File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), `FTP may run in active or passive mode`, as the figure below. In active mode, the client requires a listening port for incoming data from the server. However, due to the listening port of client for FTP server is random assigned, you can not prepare in advance to add the port in NSG inbound rules. So you should use `passive mode` in the client side on Azure VM with [`FTP.set_pasv(True)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_pasv) or without `FTP.set_pasv(False)`.

   [image]

   [image]
2. For the issue `421 Data timeout. Reconnect. Sorry.`, please check the timeout setting in your FTP server, such as the `data_connection_timeout` property of `vsftpd.conf` file of `vftp`, to set enough long value of time out
3. Try to set a `timeout` value longer then the global default setting for [`ftplib.FTP(host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', timeout=None, source_address=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) function.

   [image]
4. Try to use function [`FTP.set_debuglevel(level)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_debuglevel) to debug output more details for your script to find out the possible reason.

   [image]

Hope it helps.